# Custom like predicate to handle custom user defined types (Hibernate UserType)

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa-2.0, hibernate-criteria

I recently stumbled upon a problem where I have to build a JPA criteria with like predicate that accepts a custom type that is an implementation of [`UserType`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/usertype/UserType.html). The custom type I'm dealing with is nothing more than `String` wrapped with some additional info.

I've done it for Hibernate criteria with implementing the [`Criterion`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/criterion/Criterion.html) interface from Hibernate and it works fine.

I have to do the same now for JPA, but the Hibernates implementation of [`Predicate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/Predicate.html), the [`LikePredicate`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/jpa/criteria/predicate/LikePredicate.html) which is created when calling:

> CriteriaBuilderImpl.like(Expression< String >, String)

seems quite complicated.

What I need is something like:

> ...like(Expression< MyUserType >, MyUserType)

Has any one done such a thing yet and can offer me some hints?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was solved with a helper method where `CustomString` is the custom `UserType`:

```
public static Predicate addLike(CriteriaBuilder cb, Path<CustomString> path, String val)
{
    return cb.like(cb.lower(path.as(String.class)), val.toLowerCase());
}
```